# Вывести все id категорий к новости в текущей категории. SQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть скрипт вывода статей из базы данных.

3 таблицы:

**news**

news_id title

1 Вышел новый Audi A4

**categories**

category_id category_title

1 Новости мира

2 Новости автомобилей

3 Новости спорта

**news_categories**

news_id category_id

1 1

1 2

Чтобы вывести все новости на главной, при этом указывая все id категорий новости, делаю такой запрос:

> select group_concat(nc.category_id) as ids, n.news_id id, n.news_title
>   title from news n join news_category nc on nc.news_id = n.news_id 
>   group by n.news_id

Этот запрос отлично выводит все новости и id категорий к новости.

**Вывод:**

ids     id  title

1,2     1   Вышел новый Audi A4

Но, как поступить, если нужен список новостей с id всех категорий на странице определенной категории?

Например, если мы находимся в категории 1:

> select group_concat(nc.category_id) as ids, n.news_id id, n.news_title
>   title from news n join news_category nc on nc.news_id = n.news_id 
>   where nc.category_id = 1 group by n.news_id

**Вывод:**

ids     id  title

1   1   Вышел новый Audi A4

А нужно, чтобы и id 2-ой категории был, как раньше.

Напрашивается решение с дополнительным запросом (select category_id from news_category where news_id = N) внутри while при выводе на php, но получится если на странице 15 новостей, будет 15 запросов к базе.

Может быть кто-то решил подобную задачу как-то иначе?

Comment: в вашем втором запросе не хватает группировки по `n.news_title`, однако несколько не понятно, зачем вам одни id категорий без их названий? да и в целом, зачем склеивать их в строку? чтобы потом разделять обратно что ли?

Comment: teran, вы все правильно поняли. 1) Получая id всех категорий к новости, потом по id можно получить заголовки и ссылки уже из одного готового массива категорий. 2) Можете уточнить про группировку по n.news_title? Сейчас и без нее результат был такой, как нужно. Я в sql совсем недавно.

Comment: а, пардоньте, не так понял ваш вопрос. но в любом случае, для корректного запроса необходимо news_title добавить в group by. Mysql несколько гибок в этом, но любая другая СУБД выдаст вам ошибку о том, что в инструкции select есть поля, которые отсутствуют в group by/